# Expressing a force in components

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, newtonian-gravity

If there is an object on some ramp, how do I express its weight in terms of vectors orthogonal and parallel to the ramp surface?

For example, if the object has a weight $\vec W=m\vec g$, then how do I express it in terms of orthonormal vectors along and perpendicular to the ramp's surface?

Comment: Please show what you have done so far etc. and don't expect anyone to feed you the answer.

Comment: I have proposed an edit to the question to make it less home--work--like.

Comment: Orthonormal one:  When inclination is 90-degrree, it is equal to W but when inclination is 0-degree it is zero. When inclination is 60-degrees, it is half of W.

Comment: I have tried mgsin(90-theta),mgcos(90-theta) and that is incorrect.

Comment: I meant to say that mgcos(90-theta) is the x component and mgsin(90-theta) is the y component.

Comment: @MaxS: By 90, I'm assuming you mean 90 degrees (which in my head is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians). Since $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)=\cos\theta$, and $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)=\sin\theta$, you could just say $\cos\theta$, and, $\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

[Free body diagram - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_body_diagram) + trigonometry is always the way to go. You can pick wathever the vectors or angles you want, if you're consistent with the quantities.